# What is the Python equivalent of Matlab's tic and toc functions?

Tags: python, matlab, timing

What is the Python equivalent of Matlab's [tic and toc functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/tic.html)?

Comment: If you really want the direct equivalent, just call `tic = time.time()` and `toc = time.time()`, then `print toc-tic, 'sec Elapsed'` As folks have said below, though, `timeit` is more robust.

Comment: I seem to get better results using @JoeKington's approach in conjunction with timeit.default_timer(), like this for example:  `tic = timeit.default_timer(); (U,S,V) = np.linalg.svd(A); toc = timeit.default_timer()`, then `print toc-tic`.

Comment: The library pytictoc seems most conveinent, syntax is even slightly neater than ttictoc below. https://pypi.org/project/pytictoc/

Answer (score 236, accepted):

Apart from `timeit` which ThiefMaster mentioned, a simple way to do it is just (after importing `time`):

```
t = time.time()
# do stuff
elapsed = time.time() - t
```

I have a helper class I like to use:

```
class Timer(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name

    def __enter__(self):
        self.tstart = time.time()

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        if self.name:
            print('[%s]' % self.name,)
        print('Elapsed: %s' % (time.time() - self.tstart))
```

It can be used as a context manager:

```
with Timer('foo_stuff'):
   # do some foo
   # do some stuff
```

Sometimes I find this technique more convenient than `timeit` - it all depends on what you want to measure.

Comment: Thanks, the helper class like yours is what I need =)

Comment: Do not use this kind of technique ever. If `timeit` (http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) is not sufficient for you, then harness your code execution with some decent profiler (http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html). Even if the `tic, toc` paradigm is common in Matlab, please don't try to duplicate that kind of stupidity in `python`. There exists really better tools to do such evaluations much reasonable way in `python`. Thanks

Comment: @eat: I respectfully disagree. People have been using the unix `time` command to measure runtimes of programs for ever, and this method replicates this inside Python code. I see nothing wrong with it, as long as it's the right tool for the job. `timeit` isn't always that, and a profiler is a much more heavyweight solution for most needs

Comment: For the last line I would suggest `print 'Elapsed: %.2f seconds % (time.time() - self.tstart)'`. It is hard to understand without the %.2f. Thanks for great idea.

Comment: This looks very convenient at first glance, but in practice requires one to indent the code block one wants to time, which can be quite inconvenient depending on the length of the code block and the editor of choice. Still an elegant solution, which behaves correctly in the case of nested use.

Comment: I think you want `elapsed = t - time.time()`, instead of `elapsed = time.time() - t`. In the latter elapsed will be negative. I suggested this change as an edit.

Comment: @rysqui - Isn't the _current time_ always a larger number than a _previous time_? I would think that `elapsed = time.time() - t` is the form that always yields a positive value.

Comment: @ScottSmith hmmm. yeah i have no idea what i was thinking when I wrote that comment 2 years ago. It seems super wrong, and you seem super correct. Not sure what i was thinking.

Comment: In Python 3, you can use the same code, but with slight modifications to the print statements. [See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50957722/1048186).

Comment: @CanKavaklıoğlu I have made your suggested edit in [my answer updated for Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50957722/1048186).

Comment: Don't use this in production because the clock might have been changed between readings, possibly backwards leading to a negative interval. The change could be by the user, daylight savings changeover, time zone change, or gradual clock correction causing a consistent error in the measured interval.

Answer (score 52):

I had the same question when I migrated to python from Matlab.  With the help of this thread I was able to construct an *exact* analog of the Matlab `tic()` and `toc()` functions.  Simply insert the following code at the top of your script.

```
import time

def TicTocGenerator():
    # Generator that returns time differences
    ti = 0           # initial time
    tf = time.time() # final time
    while True:
        ti = tf
        tf = time.time()
        yield tf-ti # returns the time difference

TicToc = TicTocGenerator() # create an instance of the TicTocGen generator

# This will be the main function through which we define both tic() and toc()
def toc(tempBool=True):
    # Prints the time difference yielded by generator instance TicToc
    tempTimeInterval = next(TicToc)
    if tempBool:
        print( "Elapsed time: %f seconds.\n" %tempTimeInterval )

def tic():
    # Records a time in TicToc, marks the beginning of a time interval
    toc(False)
```

That's it! Now we are ready to fully use `tic()` and `toc()` just as in Matlab.  For example

```
tic()

time.sleep(5)

toc() # returns "Elapsed time: 5.00 seconds."
```

Actually, this is more versatile than the built-in Matlab functions.  Here, you could create another instance of the `TicTocGenerator` to keep track of multiple operations, or just to time things differently. For instance, while timing a script, we can now time each piece of the script seperately, as well as the entire script. (I will provide a concrete example)

```
TicToc2 = TicTocGenerator() # create another instance of the TicTocGen generator

def toc2(tempBool=True):
    # Prints the time difference yielded by generator instance TicToc2
    tempTimeInterval = next(TicToc2)
    if tempBool:
    print( "Elapsed time 2: %f seconds.\n" %tempTimeInterval )

def tic2():
    # Records a time in TicToc2, marks the beginning of a time interval
    toc2(False)
```

Now you should be able to time two separate things: In the following example, we time the total script and parts of a script separately.

```
tic()

time.sleep(5)

tic2()

time.sleep(3)

toc2() # returns "Elapsed time 2: 5.00 seconds."

toc() # returns "Elapsed time: 8.00 seconds."
```

Actually, you do not even need to use `tic()` each time. If you have a series of commands that you want to time, then you can write

```
tic()

time.sleep(1)

toc() # returns "Elapsed time: 1.00 seconds."

time.sleep(2)

toc() # returns "Elapsed time: 2.00 seconds."

time.sleep(3)

toc() # returns "Elapsed time: 3.00 seconds."

# and so on...
```

I hope that this is helpful.

Comment: “this is more versatile than the built-in Matlab functions” — I suggest you read [the MATLAB docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tic.html), you’ll see your solution is not nearly as convenient when measuring multiple things at once. And of course this is not an exact analog.

Answer (score 25):

The absolute best analog of tic and toc would be to simply define them in python.

```
def tic():
    #Homemade version of matlab tic and toc functions
    import time
    global startTime_for_tictoc
    startTime_for_tictoc = time.time()

def toc():
    import time
    if 'startTime_for_tictoc' in globals():
        print "Elapsed time is " + str(time.time() - startTime_for_tictoc) + " seconds."
    else:
        print "Toc: start time not set"
```

Then you can use them as:

```
tic()
# do stuff
toc()
```

Comment: This will not behave correctly in the case of nested use of `tic` and `toc`, which Matlab supports. A little more sophistication would be required.

Comment: I have implemented similar functions in my own code when I needed some basic timing. I would however remove the `import time` outside of both functions, since it can take potentially quite some time.

Comment: If you insist on using this technique, and you need it to handle nested tic/toc, make the global a list and let `tic` push to it and `toc` pop from it.

Comment: Also I read elsewhere that `timeit.default_timer()` is better than `time.time()` because `time.clock()` might be more appropriate depending on OS

Comment: @AhmedFasih That's what my answer does, though more things could be improved.

Comment: FYI: MATLAB does not support nested `tic`/`toc` through a stack, you need to use `tic`’s output argument for that.

Answer (score 20):

Usually, IPython's `%time`, `%timeit`, `%prun` and `%lprun` (if one has `line_profiler` installed) satisfy my profiling needs quite well. However, a use case for `tic-toc`-like functionality arose when I tried to profile calculations that were interactively driven, i.e., by the user's mouse motion in a GUI. I felt like spamming `tic`s and `toc`s in the sources while testing interactively would be the fastest way to reveal the bottlenecks. I went with Eli Bendersky's `Timer` class, but wasn't fully happy, since it required me to change the indentation of my code, which can be inconvenient in some editors and confuses the version control system. Moreover, there may be the need to measure the time between points in different functions, which wouldn't work with the `with` statement. After trying lots of Python cleverness, here is the simple solution that I found worked best:

```
from time import time
_tstart_stack = []

def tic():
    _tstart_stack.append(time())

def toc(fmt="Elapsed: %s s"):
    print fmt % (time() - _tstart_stack.pop())
```

Since this works by pushing the starting times on a stack, it will work correctly for multiple levels of `tic`s and `toc`s. It also allows one to change the format string of the `toc` statement to display additional information, which I liked about Eli's `Timer` class.

For some reason I got concerned with the overhead of a pure Python implementation, so I tested  a C extension module as well:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <mach/mach_time.h>
#define MAXDEPTH 100

uint64_t start[MAXDEPTH];
int lvl=0;

static PyObject* tic(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    start[lvl++] = mach_absolute_time();
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

static PyObject* toc(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
return PyFloat_FromDouble(
        (double)(mach_absolute_time() - start[--lvl]) / 1000000000L);
}

static PyObject* res(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    return tic(NULL, NULL), toc(NULL, NULL);
}

static PyMethodDef methods[] = {
    {"tic", tic, METH_NOARGS, "Start timer"},
    {"toc", toc, METH_NOARGS, "Stop timer"},
    {"res", res, METH_NOARGS, "Test timer resolution"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
inittictoc(void) {
    Py_InitModule("tictoc", methods);
}
```

This is for MacOSX, and I have omitted code to check if `lvl` is out of bounds for brevity. While `tictoc.res()` yields a resolution of about 50 nanoseconds on my system, I found that the jitter of measuring any Python statement is easily in the microsecond range (and much more when used from IPython). At this point, the overhead of the Python implementation becomes negligible, so that it can be used with the same confidence as the C implementation.

I found that the usefulness of the `tic-toc`-approach is practically limited to code blocks that take more than 10 microseconds to execute. Below that, averaging strategies like in `timeit` are required to get a faithful measurement.

Answer (score 17):

You can use `tic` and `toc` from `ttictoc`. Install it with

```
pip install ttictoc
```

And just import them in your script as follow

```py
from ttictoc import tic,toc
tic()
# Some code
print(toc())
```

Answer (score 8):

I have just created a module [tictoc.py] for achieving nested tic tocs, which is what Matlab does.

```
from time import time

tics = []

def tic():
    tics.append(time())

def toc():
    if len(tics)==0:
        return None
    else:
        return time()-tics.pop()
```

And it works this way:

```
from tictoc import tic, toc

# This keeps track of the whole process
tic()

# Timing a small portion of code (maybe a loop)
tic()

# -- Nested code here --

# End
toc()  # This returns the elapse time (in seconds) since the last invocation of tic()
toc()  # This does the same for the first tic()
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Nice replication of tic/toc from MATLAB!

Comment: I must warn you that this might not behave as desired when used simultaneously by more than 1 module, since (AFAIK) modules behave like singletons.

Comment: This is not how MATLAB’s tic/top works. There is no stack. You can call `toc` repeatedly to get the time from the same last `tic`. Nested timings work through an output argument to `tic`, which you then pass in to `toc`.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) module.
It's not really equivalent but if the code you want to time is inside a function you can easily use it.

Comment: Yes, `timeit` is best for benchmarks. It doesn't even have to be a single function, you can pass abritarily complex statements.

Comment: Well, passing code that is not an extremely simple function call as a string is very ugly.

Comment: It also work with lambdas like this (straight from the documentation):
`timeit.timeit(lambda: "-".join(map(str, range(100))), number=10000)`

Answer (score 5):

```
pip install easy-tictoc
```

In the code:

```
from tictoc import tic, toc

tic()

#Some code

toc()
```

---

<sup>Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library.</sup>

Comment: Please don't simply copy another answer, even if it is your own.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59271862/8239061

Answer (score 4):

Updating [Eli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5849861/1048186) to Python 3:

```
class Timer(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None, filename=None):
        self.name = name
        self.filename = filename

    def __enter__(self):
        self.tstart = time.time()

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        message = 'Elapsed: %.2f seconds' % (time.time() - self.tstart)
        if self.name:
            message = '[%s] ' % self.name + message
        print(message)
        if self.filename:
            with open(self.filename,'a') as file:
                print(str(datetime.datetime.now())+": ",message,file=file)
```

Just like Eli's, it can be used as a context manager:

```
import time 
with Timer('Count'):
    for i in range(0,10_000_000):
        pass
```

Output:

```
[Count] Elapsed: 0.27 seconds
```

I have also updated it to print the units of time reported (seconds) and trim the number of digits as suggested by Can, and with the option of also appending to a log file. You must import datetime to use the logging feature:

```
import time
import datetime 
with Timer('Count', 'log.txt'):    
    for i in range(0,10_000_000):
        pass
```

Answer (score 3):

Building on Stefan and antonimmo's answers, I ended up putting

```
def Tictoc():
    start_stack = []
    start_named = {}

    def tic(name=None):
        if name is None:
            start_stack.append(time())
        else:
            start_named[name] = time()

    def toc(name=None):
        if name is None:
            start = start_stack.pop()
        else:
            start = start_named.pop(name)
        elapsed = time() - start
        return elapsed
    return tic, toc
```

in a `utils.py` module, and I use it with a

```
from utils import Tictoc
tic, toc = Tictoc()
```

This way

- you can simply use `tic()`, `toc()` and nest them like in Matlab
- alternatively, you can name them: `tic(1)`, `toc(1)` or `tic('very-important-block')`, `toc('very-important-block')` and timers with different names won't interfere
- importing them this way prevents interference between modules using it.

(here toc does not print the elapsed time, but returns it.)

Comment: MATLAB’s tic/toc don’t nest this way, there’a no stack. I do like the idea of named timers.

Answer (score 1):

I changed @Eli Bendersky's answer a little bit to use the ctor `__init__()` and dtor `__del__()` to do the timing, so that it can be used more conveniently without indenting the original code:

```
class Timer(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name
        self.tstart = time.time()

    def __del__(self):
        if self.name:
            print '%s elapsed: %.2fs' % (self.name, time.time() - self.tstart)
        else:
            print 'Elapsed: %.2fs' % (time.time() - self.tstart)
```

To use, simple put Timer("blahblah") at the beginning of some local scope. Elapsed time will be printed at the end of the scope:

```
for i in xrange(5):
    timer = Timer("eigh()")
    x = numpy.random.random((4000,4000));
    x = (x+x.T)/2
    numpy.linalg.eigh(x)
    print i+1
timer = None
```

It prints out:

```
1
eigh() elapsed: 10.13s
2
eigh() elapsed: 9.74s
3
eigh() elapsed: 10.70s
4
eigh() elapsed: 10.25s
5
eigh() elapsed: 11.28s
```

Comment: An issue with this implementation is the fact, that `timer` is not deleted after the last call, if any other code follows after the `for` loop. To get the last timer value, one should delete or overwrite the `timer` after the `for` loop, e.g. via `timer = None`.

Comment: @bastelflp Just realized that I misunderstood what you meant... Your suggestion has been incorporated in the code now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done using a wrapper. Very general way of keeping time.

The wrapper in this example code wraps any function and prints the amount of time needed to execute the function:

```
def timethis(f):
    import time

    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        r = f(*args, **kwargs)
        print "Executing {0} took {1} seconds".format(f.func_name,  time.time()-start)
        return r
    return wrapped

@timethis
def thistakestime():
    for x in range(10000000):
        pass

thistakestime()
```

Comment: The wrapper function, timethis is called a decorator.

A bit more detailed explanation, here: 
https://medium.com/pythonhive/python-decorator-to-measure-the-execution-time-of-methods-fa04cb6bb36d

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for my profiling needs:

```
from time import time
import inspect

def tic():
    tic.t = time()

def toc(message=None):
    time_elapsed = time() - tic.t
    if message is None:
        message = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_lineno
    print(message, time_elapsed)
    tic.t = time()
    return time_elapsed
```

Then you can just paste a lot of `toc()`s in your code, and you have a pretty powerful profiler. (message defaults to the caller's code line in file)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of @Maxim, here is a simplified solution:

```py
def tictoc():
    """Python implementation of MATLAB tic-toc functionality."""
    from time import perf_counter_ns
    hashmap = {}
    def tic(key: str=None) -> None:
        """named tic method"""
        hashmap[key] = perf_counter_ns()
        return None
    def toc(key: str=None) -> float:
        """named toc method"""
        initial_ns = hashmap[key]
        current_ns = perf_counter_ns()
        elapsed_ns = current_ns - initial_ns
        elapsed_s  = elapsed_ns / (10**9)  # convert ns to s
        print(f"Elapsed time is {elapsed_s} seconds.")
        return elapsed_s  
    return tic, toc
```

Assuming it is stored in a file called `utils.py`, it is used in the following manner:

```py
from utils import tictoc

tic, toc = tictoc()

tic()
toc()
toc()
tic()
toc()

tic('foo')
toc('foo')
toc('foo')

toc()
```

Unlike the original, this version does not crash when you run `toc()` multiple times and properly resets when running `tic` while retaining the key-value timer functionality. It also removes an unnecessary list/array data structure and multiple conditional branches in the code, which induce slowdowns. Hashmap lookup times are constant at O^1, which is faster than resizing arrays. Also, I have switched to the `perf_counter_ns` timer, which is based on `perf_counter` and avoids the precision loss caused by the `float` type.

If anyone wants to go lower level, here is a version using the Python C API:

```
// tictoc.c
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN  // REQUIRED
#include <Python.h>       // Python C API

#include <stdint.h>       // uint64_t
#include <time.h>         // timespec
#include <sys/time.h>     // time types
#include <stdio.h>        // printf

typedef struct {
    uint64_t initial_ns;
    uint64_t current_ns;
    uint64_t elapsed_ns;
    double elapsed_s;
} timer;

timer t;

struct timespec ts;  // C11

// Unix POSIX clock time scaled to microseconds (us; 10^6 sec)
uint64_t posix_clock_time () {
    timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
    return ts.tv_sec * 1000000000 + ts.tv_nsec;  // ns = 10^-9 s
}

// tic
static PyObject* tic(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) {
    t.initial_ns = posix_clock_time();
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

// toc
static PyObject* toc(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) {
    t.current_ns = posix_clock_time();
    t.elapsed_ns = t.current_ns - t.initial_ns;
    t.elapsed_s  = (double)t.elapsed_ns / (double)1000000000.0;  // s = 10^9 ns
    printf("Elapsed time is %f seconds.\n", t.elapsed_s);
    return PyFloat_FromDouble(t.elapsed_s);
}

static PyMethodDef methods[] = {
    {"tic", tic, METH_NOARGS, "Start timer"},
    {"toc", toc, METH_NOARGS, "Stop timer"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef tictoc = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "tictoc",    // name of module
    "A timer function analogous to MATLAB's tic-toc.",  // module documentation, may be NULL
    -1,          // size of per-interpreter state of module; -1 if module keeps state in global variables
    methods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_tictoc(void) {
    return PyModule_Create(&tictoc);
}
```

Install it with a `setup.py` file:

```py
# setup.py
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module1 = Extension(
    'tictoc',
    sources = ['tictoc.c']
)

setup(name = 'tictoc',
    version = '1.0',
    description = 'The tictoc package',
    ext_modules = [module1]
)
```

From the command line, run `python setup.py build` and Bob's your uncle. This compiles to a shared library that provides basic tic-toc functionality similar to MATLAB:

```py
from tictoc import tic, toc

tic()
toc()
toc()

tic()
toc()
toc()
```