# How can I get the simulation time of a model in Dymola using the Python interface?

Tags: python, dymola

I am using Dymola's python_interface and want to simulate a set of models:

```
import platform

from dymola.dymola_interface import DymolaInterface
from dymola.dymola_exception import DymolaException

osString = platform.system()
isWindows = osString.startswith("Win")

with open('ModelList.txt', 'r') as f:
    models = f.read().splitlines()

for model in models:
    dymola = None
    try:
        dymola = DymolaInterface("C:\\Program Files\\Dymola 2018 FD01\\bin64\\Dymola.exe")

        result = dymola.simulateModel(model)
        if not result:
            print("Simulation failed:")
            log = dymola.getLastErrorLog()
            print(log)
        else:
            print("OK")
    except DymolaException as ex:
        print(("Error: " + str(ex)))
    finally:
        if dymola is not None:
            dymola.close()
            dymola = None
```

Basically, this is the example given in the Dymola manual (with the added for-loop). Now I want to get the models' simulation time and write it to a (csv-)file.

The simulation time is also written to the log-file, but is there a way to get it directly? The results of the simulation are written to a .mat file which is fine for me.

Thank You for your help!

Comment: Would setting the flag `OutputCPUtime=true` be sufficient?

Comment: Do you mean the simulation end time or the required cpu time?

Comment: If I set `OutputCPUtime=True` how can I store the time within a string or float?
@marco I mean the required cpu time. The 'stopTime' is known.

Comment: A comment to your code: I would put the model loop inside the try statement. Currently you are opening and closing dymola for every model in ModelList.txt, which gives a big and unnecessary overhead

Comment: Yes, you are right, I changed this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the required CPU time as variable into the simulation result with the flag `OutputCPUtime=true`. Then you can use the `simulateExtendedModel` command to get the final value of this variable.

Add the following into your try section and it should do what you want:

```
dymola = DymolaInterface("C:\\Program Files\\Dymola 2018 FD01\\bin64\\Dymola.exe")
dymola.ExecuteCommand("OutputCPUtime=true")
result, values = dymola.simulateExtendedModel(model, finalNames= ['CPUtime'])
cpu_time = values[0]
```

As an alternative you can first translate your model and then measure in python how long the simulate command takes to execute, using one of the methods described in [tic, toc functions analog in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849800/tic-toc-functions-analog-in-python#5849861)

This could then look like as follows:

```
    dymola = DymolaInterface("C:\\Program Files\\Dymola 2018 FD01\\bin64\\Dymola.exe")
    dymola.translateModel(model)
    t = time.time()
    result = dymola.simulateModel(model)
    elapsed = time.time() - t
```

Comment: Thank you,this just worked out. 
Still a question: This cpuTime is always a bit bigger than the 'CPU time for integration'. The latter only covers the simulation AFAIK, does the cputime contain more actions (like translation time)?

Comment: You are right, the CPUtime apparently includes more than the simulation time. If you activate the flag in Dymola and plot the variable after a simulation, you see that the plot starts with an offset - I assume that this is the translation time.